# Upload multiple files on android using wildcard and command line

Tags: adb, windows, file-transfer

I designed my Android application so that it can load CSS files dynamically. I am not working on the design and I copy CSS files on my device every time I make a change.

Doing this in explorer is tedious. I would like a command line script that would copy all `*.css` files and upload them to `/storage/extSdCard/`. I tried this, using `adb push`:

```
D:\ ... \resources>adb push *.css /storage/extSdCard/
  cannot stat '*.css': No such file or directory
```

Even copying one file doesn't work:

```
D:\ ... \resources>adb push black_style.css /storage/extSdCard/black_style.css
  failed to copy 'black_style.css' to '/storage/extSdCard/black_style.css': Permission denied
```

In explorer, I simply navigate in `Computer\GT-S7710\Card` and paste the files. Why doesn't my command line work and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you first confirm that adb has the permission to write external SD card at all? Can you try doing a random file push with `adb push ANY_FILE /sdcard/` and see if /sdcard/ lists the file later? If yes, tell us where does /sdcard/ points to? To external or to internal SD card.

Comment: `extSdCard` points to external sdCard, as would one expect. And no, I was not able to write any other files in the SD card either. But I have no problem copying them there using Windows Explorer. I thought maybe android might have support for command line copying that works, I was wrong obviously.

Comment: Windows Explorer does that because either you've your card mounted in USB Mass Storage mode (which I don't think so) or you're using MTP (which is altogether a different protocol and gives different privilege to user). Here is the answer: [ADB push multiple files with the same extension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12901240). You now only have to figure out why adb can't write to ext SD card.

Comment: Trouble with `adb push <source> <target>` is that `source` and `target` must be of the same type. So if `source` is a file, `target` must be a file. `adb push <file> <directory>` will fail – but that's what your first command specifies. The second issue, as @Firelord already pointed out, are permissions. I bet your device runs Android 5+ (and thus restricts access to the SDCard). MTP gets that permission granted (wouldn't make sense otherwise), ADB it seems not (which sounds strange to me).

Comment: Just to add to @Izzy 's note on android 5+ restricting access. In the explorer on the phone, there is some sort of unlock SD card. It asked me to do so when trying to write to SD. I however use CM, so it might be a bit different. Only speculation, but can't file explorers like TotalCMD allow write, if they can remount?

Comment: @TheBro21 Mount is something different. Write protection for the SD card is not done by mounting it r/o, but by using file permissions (ownership/group) and (in simple terms) some "watchdog process". It's not a "direct write", but rather handing the stuff that should be written to a system process doing the job. So either ADB must use that API – or must have "ownership".

Comment: @Izzy Since ADB needs that ownership, then would `adb root` be enough to bypass write protection?

Comment: I cannot give references on this or say "sure", but considering what `adb root` usually does (shutting down the `adbd` on the device and restarting it with superuser privileges), that indeed should grant ADB "full power", yes. But to my knowledge, this does not work on stock ROMs, you will get some error message like "not on production builds".

Comment: @Izzy On CM it runs fine. On the stock ROM it is problematic, but eventually I somehow got superuser request messages "adb" from superSU, and it worked. So perhaps it works on some stock ROMs

Comment: CM is a different case of course. Great to hear about the superuser requests on stock, never heard that before! I've got it running on a stock ROM here as well (by replacing `adbd` and the boot image ;) – another possibility (on rooted devices) is using chainfire's "insecure adbd" (an app you start on the device to switch `adbd` into root mode). // Do you want to sum that all up in an answer, so we can cleanup the comments here?

Comment: While you act on "extSdCard", you're acting on a FUSE filesystem. This kind of filesystems act as a protection against unauthorized file access (and chmoding as well). Try to push the file to **/mnt/media_rw** or **/mnt/media_rw/sdcard1**, depending upon which Android version you have.